# Keeping the modal window open after unsuccessful login attempt in a Rails app using FancyBox 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, fancybox-2, rails-admin

I have a basic Rails app running with rails_admin, devise, and cancan. I am using FancyBox 2 to display a lightbox type login modal window when the user clicks the Client Login link. It is behaving as desired with the exception that when a user enters incorrect credentials, the user is then redirected to /users/sign_in instead of just bringing that page up again in the modal window with a flash message stating that the username or password is incorrect. I have two questions:

1. How can I make the FancyBox 2 modal window continue to display if the user submits incorrect credentials, and display the flash message stating that they need to re-enter their credentials within the modal window?
2. How could I prevent users from going to the /users/sign_in page unless it is in a FancyBox 2 modal window? Right now, if the user types: www.example.com/users/sign_in, then they will go to the full page for login. I would ideally like this to trigger the FancyBox 2 modal window.

Here are the relevant files:

app/views/layouts/appliction.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Test App</title>
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>  
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "jquery.fancybox.css", :media => "all" %> 
   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
   <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.fancybox.js" %>
   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

   <%= flash[:notice] %>
   <%= flash[:alert] %>

   <%= yield %>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.fancybox').fancybox({
         'onStart': function() {
            $('#fancybox-outer').css({'background':'transparent'});
            $('#fancybox-bg-n,#fancybox-bg-ne,#fancybox-bg-e,#fancybox-bg-se,#fancybox-bg-s,#fancybox-bg-sw,#fancybox-bg-w,#fancybox-bg-nw')
               .css({'background-image':'none'});
         }
      })
   });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

app/views/welcome/index.html.erb (root_path)

```
<h1>Test App</h1>

<% if user_signed_in? %>
<a href="app">Dashboard</a>
<% else %>
<a class="fancybox fancybox.ajax" href="users/sign_in">Client Login</a>
<% end %>
```

app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
   <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
   <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div> 

   <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
   <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

   <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
      <div><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></div>
   <% end -%>

   <div><%= f.submit "Sign in" %></div>
   <% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

routes.rb

```
TestApp::Application.routes.draw do
   get "welcome/index"
   resources :containers
   resources :scales
   devise_for :users
   mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/app', :as => 'rails_admin'
   root :to => 'welcome#index'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You may want to look at an ajax solution for this issue. Passing `remote: true` to the form should do that.  Look at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers on how to override the sessions controller so you can add a js template which you can use to show error messages.
2. You should look at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-routes so you can redirect users to your home page when they try to go to that login url.  I think you can just pass a params which you can check against to trigger a javascript event that opens fancybox